# Arguments for main() in C++

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

I have been following the book Flex & Bison from Levine and I see the following piece of code:

```
main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{
    if(argc > 1) {
        if(!(yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
            perror(argv[1]);
            return (1);
        }
    }
    yylex();
```

I find it little hard to understand this part, for example, the first line:

```
char **argv;
```

for what I can see it should be related to this part:

```
if(!(yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
```

so I can interpret that it is reading an input operation, this because of the "r", and the `argv[1]` refers to the input of a line by console. Is it like that? I have no clue why the author is using a double pointer to argv. I suppose that when there is not a valid input it prints a descriptive error with `perror()`, but in which case this could happen?

Comment: Your book is apparently an old book that still uses K&R C, the original C language version. Current, modern, C/C++ will declare main as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, so you might want to hunt around a more recent book, to complement this one.

Comment: Yuor question has exactly nothing to do with either [tag:bison] or [tag:flex-lexer]. It is simply about `main()`.

Comment: Helpful: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: https://jameshfisher.com/2016/11/27/c-k-and-r/

Answer (score 1):

The `char **argv` is interpreted by the C++ compiler as the same as `char* argv[]`, i.e, a pointer to an array of pointers. As you may already know, `argv` represents the arguments passed to the program executable, e.g. `./program arg1 arg2`. You can think of `argv` as an array of strings (C-strings) if that simplifies things, each element of the array is an argument.

Your interpretation is basically right. It checks that there is at least one argument `argc > 0` (argument count), then uses the first argument (`argv[1]` as `argv[0]` actually refers to the program name `./program`) as a file name. It then tries to open a file of name `argv[1]` for reading. If this fails, the `fopen`returns `NULL`. This can happen if the file doesn't exist.